# The difference between else if and else {if}

Tags: c

Code A:

```
if () 
...
else {
   if (cond == 1) 
       /* do something */ 
}
```

Code B:

```
if ()
...
else if (cond == 1) 
   /* do something */
```

If there exists differences between code A and Code B?

Comment: no technical difference, just formatting preference

Comment: With `Code B` you have to maintain a single fallback in else block if the condition is not met. But in `Code A ` it can be messy.

Comment: After compiling Code A and Code B respectively, we found that the assembly codes of the two are exactly the same.

Comment: @YaFengLuo, how have you compiled the code if you don't know what is in place of the `...` or in the first condition?

Comment: Well, I think the detail in ``...`` is not important. I writh simple logic in each branch.

Answer (score 2):

There only is a potential difference, which becomes visible with slightly extended example code
(please excuse the intentionally misleading indentation, it is exactly the problem you need to keep in mind in this kind of situation):

```
if () 
...
else {
   if (cond == 1) 
       do_something();     /* executed on !1st and 2nd condition */
       do_somthing_else(); /* executed on !1st but unaffecated by 2nd condition */
}
```

```
if ()
...
else if (cond == 1) 
    do_something();       /* executed on !1st and 2nd condition */
    do_something_else();  /* ALWAYS executed */
```

Comment: morality : always indent in the right way

Answer (score 0):

There is none. There is even no difference to this code:

```c
if ()
...
else if (cond == 1) 
...
else if (cond == 2) 
...
else if (cond == 3)
```

You usually see `else { if() }` in this kind of code:

```
if ()
...
else
{
    if ()
    ...
    else if()
    ...
    else
    ...
}
```